# PHP: Check if array values exist in another array

Tags: php

i have created a array like this :

```
$foods_customer = array(["meal"=>1,"rice"=>1];
```

when i return this array , looks like :

```
[{meal: 1, rice: 1}]
0: {meal: 1, rice: 1}
meal: 1
rice: 1
```

and i have another array like this :

$foods , when i return , looks like this .

```
[{meal: 1}, {meal: 1, rice: 1}]
0: {meal: 1}
meal: 1
1: {meal: 1, rice: 1}
meal: 1
rice: 1
```

i wanna check if array $foods_customer , exist inside array $foods.

in this case , must return true , bit if $foods_customer was like this :

```
[{meal: 1, rice: 1 , chesse:1}]
    0: {meal: 1, rice: 1,chesse:1}
    meal: 1
    rice: 1
    chesse:1
```

so , return false .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily with just foreach and Identical checking. First make a loop of your main array then make another loop inside of it and then check the array identically.

Try this out:

```
$foods_customer = array(["meal"=>1,"rice"=>1]);
$foods  = array(["meal"=>1 ],["meal"=>1,"rice"=>1]);

$res = false;
foreach( $foods as $food ){
    foreach( $foods_customer as $fc ){
        if( $fc === $food ){
            $res  = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo $res;
```

Comment: always return null , with dd($res) return false.

Comment: what is 'dd' @SaroBeatbox

Comment: like a var_dump on laravel .

Comment: plz make sure the array is same as I inserted - @SaroBeatbox

Comment: when i copy your code , works , but when i'll put my enviroment code , because i using https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart to create a shopping cart .

Comment: I think your code has different value. Can you post your code here - @SaroBeatbox

Comment: when i use "===" from your code , return me false , but when i choose to "==" , return me this error :object of class Darryldecode\Cart\ItemAttributeCollection could not be converted to int

Comment: That's mean that's not an array. Maybe that's a class instance. First print that object and take a look inside of it. Then get the array and use my code. - @SaroBeatbox

Comment: Tuhin , i have edited my code , changing object to array : $cartArray = $cartCollection->toArray();  now its working like a charm . thanks.